# Programmatically check for the minimum required version of an App for Android and upgrade it

Tags: android

I have a use case in which we wish to selectively disable an Android and an until the user upgrades to a minimum required version. This question is to get design inputs and best practices for similar cases.

Typically the flow will be as follows:-

1. Upon starting the app, the main activity thread will check the presence of the current installed version. (I am looking for pointers to a Google API/TPL to achieve this programmatically).
2. Then the app checks for the minimum required version. (This can be done by maintaining the minimum required version on a rest service). However is it possible to maintain the minimum required version on Play Store?
3. Force the user to upgrade if current version < min required version. (redirecting user to App store and not letting them back into the app till they upgrade - I am also looking for code pointers for this case)

Note that this is different from the push notifications from the app store for upgrades. Unlike push notifications, this logic will allow my app to stay at some min version across my user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **check current version of your app** by using the following code if your using Android Studio.

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

I don't think maintaining installed version on play store  is possible so using a rest api for this will be the option.

**To force the user to update app**, check current version with version from api, and if conditions are not met **show them an alert dialog with two options**:- either **Exit** or **Update**. 
To launch update intent you can do something like this

```
Intent updateIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + your app package name));
```

**UPDATE:**
You can also use third party libraries to check for updates. One that I have used is [gpversionchecker](https://github.com/robohorse/gpversionchecker)

Answer (score 0):

> Upon starting the app, the main activity thread will check the
>   presence of the current installed version. (I am looking for pointers
>   to a Google API/TPL to achieve this programmatically).

YES, we can check the currently installed version of the application.

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

> Then the app checks for the minimum required version. (This can be
>   done by maintaining the minimum required version on a rest service).
>   However is it possible to maintain the minimum required version on
>   Play Store?

Maintaining the versioning with the REST services is a very good idea. Personally I would like to suggest maintaining the paths of REST services like this.

`https://www.domainname.com/api/v1/`

However, I didn't really understand your intention clearly. I guess you're talking about Android version here. So if you're thinking about the minimum API level of Android your application, then you don't have to be worried about it. Play store will take care of it.

For example, if you've uploaded an apk earlier which you want to upgrade. Play Store will keep both and user will lower Android version will get the old apk you've uploaded. You can remove the old version of your application from Google Play Developer Console too.

**Update:** You can not keep all versions of the app compatible upto a defined min level of Android version. You can keep different versions only if the minimum SDK level is changed for your application.

> Force the user to upgrade if current version < min required version.
>   (redirecting user to App store and not letting them back into the app
>   till they upgrade - I am also looking for code pointers for this case)

If some user are using the previous version of your application, you can not force them to update if its not already coded inside the application. Though we can think of an work-around here. The REST API calls may stop serving the old application as you're updating the API version number (e.g. `https://www.domainname.com/api/v2/`). So you can show them some message as a response of your APIs if response message from server is shown somewhere.

**Update:** So if you want all users to download the application update as you want them to move to server API version V2, you might have to take the choice of stopping all services for V1 and when a service is called from the old version of your application, you might give it a response like I told earlier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Umm no. App version. I wish to keep all versions of the app compatible upto a defined min level of android version. But force an upgrade for the required minimum version of the App. (e.g if I want to roll out a security feature in v2 and force everyone to v2 of the app when the highest possible app v is v3 which folks can upgrade as they wish. )

Comment: Please see the updates and let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: Kind of, its still unclear how to acquire the minimum required version of android app programatically from the play store? Essentially whether I need to maintain an rest endpoint at all?